# In grafana dashboard how to set alert mail configuration?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

- Grafana version 4.0
- Datasource influxDB

Please consider me as a beginner.
For this, how to set alerts in Grafana dashboard? alerts send to emails.

```
/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
```

I wrote SMTP config like this:

```
[smtp] 
enabled = True
host = localhost:25
user = 
If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel 
quotes. Ex """#password;"""
[emails]
welcome_email_on_sign_up = True
```

When I set alerts in Grafana dashboard its show error:

```
template variables are not supported.
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Please show or tell us what you have tried and what problems you encountered.

Comment: template variables is currently not supported in alerting. https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6557

Comment: Okay. Thank you.@CarlBergquist. But how to overcome my problem. How to set alerts in grafana dashboard? Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 7):

Configure this `/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini` file as the following:

```
[smtp]

enabled = true

host = smtp.gmail.com:587

user = Your_Email_Address@gmail.com

password = """Your_Password"""

cert_file =

key_file =

skip_verify = true

from_address = Your_Email_Address@gmail.com

from_name = Your_Name

ehlo_identity =
```

In this example, I set my own Gmail account with its SMTP:
`smtp.gmail.com` with `587(TLS)` port.

You Should find your SMTP email address with its port.

[**NOTE**]
Don't forget to put your password in **password_field**.

Comment: Don't modify the `defaults.ini` file. Instead, modify `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`

Comment: we have to modify for windows

Answer (score 1):

Mail alert grafana configuration for windows `\grafana-6.4.4.windows-amd64\grafana-6.4.4\conf\defaults.ini`

```
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = smtp.gmail.com:587
;user = 
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with triple quotes. Ex """#password;"""
;password =
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = your_mail_id
from_name = Grafana
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com
```